# List of all possible block parameters

Tags: blocks, magento-go

Is there a comprehensive list available that shows all available parameters for coding blocks?

For example for a product list. There is the category_id parameter and the column_count parameter, but what other parameters can I use?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Magento Go is Closed as of February 1st 2015

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it's even possible to get a list of all parameters for all blocks since basically you can assign parameter to a block and give it meaning either in the block class or the template file.
For example you can do this on the product list block:

```
$block->setData('doh', true); //let's assume that $block is an instance of the product list block.
//or
$block->setDoh(true);
```

Even if the parameter `doh` is not used in the block class, you can still add this in the template and give it meaning.

```
<?php if ($this->getData('doh')) : //or $this->getDoh()?>
    <span><?php echo $this->__('Homer does not approve')?></span>
<?php else : ?>
    <span><?php echo $this->__('Homer approves')?></span>
<?php endif;?>
```

Comment: ok, so *all* parameters might be a bit hard. But where can I find most of the common parameters?

Comment: @jao Marius is right, I followed this path once and can't to the same end that you can't get this information as it's done on the fly.  You have to rewrite the class in order to make this possible.  Information may have come to light since I tried, but this is where I ended, like Marius said.

Comment: So actually documentation of magento go is pretty poor then, if they can't even provide a list of possible parameters for their own code